# How to get the enclosed subpaths from a CGPath

Tags: ios, uibezierpath, cgpath

I am working on a drawing app. I have implemented the drawing string feature using CGPath. The next feature is that I can click on the view. If where I click includes an enclosed area, I can fill it with other colors. I am thinking that I need to get the enclosed subpath first, then fill color to it. Very much appreciate it if anyone can give me any idea. Thanks.

For you to understand it, I post a picture.

[image]

Comment: The green path consists of a single subpath, even though its outline creates two separate fillable areas. `CGPath` is not capable of isolating a single fillable area and deliver it as a subath. It requires an additional geometry library.

Comment: @Codo thanks for your help. Do you have any library recommended?

Comment: No, I've never used such a library and can't recommend one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, finally I found what I want is the "Flood Fill" Algorithm. If anyone wants to look for the referring article, please see [here](https://ilearnios.wordpress.com/2013/07/18/scanline-flood-fill-algorithm-with-or-without-tolerance-in-objective-c/)

Comment: Flood fill algos are usually for raster graphics, as your link demonstrates. Core Graphics is a vector renderer, so flood fill wouldn't work the same way.